# Printing special characters in a Bash scipt

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script and one of its functions is to check the length of a string (a password). The password is required to have special characters in it. I'm using ${#VAR} to check if the string is an appropriate length but special characters are being interpreted so the count is off. Below is the code in question:

```
userpass="$1"

if [[ "${#userpass}" -lt 8 ]]; then
     echo 'Short Password'
fi
```

Strings like Q7cS$ZpR8eSi and  pNbTb$IhkyUouDcZ trip it up (anything with a dollar sign or an ampersand). I've also tried using `wc -c` instead but I get the same problem

Comment: you have to single-quote references to the string. Not clear how you're feeding `$1` , but assuming cmd line, you'll have to do `./myPswdChkr.sh 'Q7cS$ZpR8eSi'` . Pluse-uno for a model shell Q. Concise and includes sample input! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, my problem is that the password is variable. The script is for  checking the complexity of a password and whether or not it adheres to the password policy of the organization. The user will enter ./myPswdChkr.sh theirpassword and the script will tell them whether or not the password is suitable.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. `userpass='pNbTb$IhkyUouDcZ'; echo ${#userpass}` Output: `16`

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it's an issue with my version of Bash or something then. `pw A2ZH$HoyL
Short Password, please make it longer than 8 characters
Please create a password with a lowercase letter
Plese insert one of @ #  $  %  &  *  +  -  = into your password
Please try again, your password did not meet the requirements` It's cutting off just before the dollar sign.

Comment: @Cyrus My `$userpass` is equal to `$1`. The script is asking the user to enter their password, so it wouldn't be encased in quotes. Maybe I'll try and hack something together in `sed` to encapsulate it in single quotes.

Comment: This Q is really about what is your use-case and specification. I can help you with a script, and then  you may reply, "this is good", or you may reply "no, I want it to do work a different way". As is, we can't tell. Do you want `echo "enter password meeting rules x,y,z" ; read password ; echo "$password" ; ...` ? Maybe you'll need `echo "'"$password"'"`. (Thats `dbl-q, singl-q,dbl-q` on both sides of `$password`). Or even `eval echo "'"$password"'"` Can't spend more time on this without a sample of your user-interaction to define the use case. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
./myPswdChkr.sh theirpa$sword
```

because the variable interpolation happens before the argument is passed to the script. `myPswdChkr.sh` only ever receives `theirpa`.

As @shellter said, it would work if the users put single-quotes around their passwords when using the script:

```
./myPswdChkr.sh 'theirpa$sword'
```

. . . but in reality, this is a terrible idea, because then their plaintext passwords get saved in command history.

Instead, run the script without arguments, just 
`./myPswdChkr.sh`, then prompt the user for the password inside the script:

```
echo -n 'PlsEntrYrPswd: '
read userpass
if [[ "${#userpass}" -lt 8 ]]; then
    echo 'Short Password'
fi
```